# Android Using Cursor to Move Through Recordset not Returning all Values

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am learning SQLite in Android Studio and having some issues outputting data from the cursor to TextView controls. Basically, I have an application that has an Insert button which statically inserts 6 records. When a Display Current Record button is clicked I want the text of three TextViews to be changed based on the content of 3 columns from the SQLite Database. However, I only seem to get three results back with my current code, and the Pet Type is not populating.

**MainActivity**

```
package com.example.devonryder.week9;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Helper mHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHelper = new Helper(this);

        // Gets the data repository in write mode

        db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        cursor = UpdateCursor();

    }


    public void Insert(View view)
    {
        // Create a new map of values, where column names are the keys
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        // Insert values
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_OWNER, "Devon");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "woofy");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_AGE, 11);
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "doge");

        // Insert the new row, returning the primary key value of the new row
        long newRowId = db.insert(Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        // Clear the insert values
        values.clear();

        // Insert more values
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_OWNER, "Steve");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "fluff");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_AGE, 12);
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "kitty");

        newRowId = db.insert(Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        values.clear();

        // Insert more values
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_OWNER, "Dan");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "jimmy boy");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_AGE, 1);
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "lizard");

        newRowId = db.insert(Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        values.clear();

        // Insert more values
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_OWNER, "James");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "axle");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_AGE, 3);
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "Tiger");

        newRowId = db.insert(Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        values.clear();

        // Insert more values
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_OWNER, "Rick");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "max");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_AGE, 7);
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "dog");

        newRowId = db.insert(Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        values.clear();

        // Insert more values
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_OWNER, "David");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "slither");
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_AGE, 2);
        values.put(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME, "snake");

        newRowId = db.insert(Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

        values.clear();

        // Set output
        TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvInsertOutput);
        output.setText("Just input " + newRowId);

        cursor = UpdateCursor();

    }

        private Cursor UpdateCursor()
    {
        String columns[] = {"owner", "PetName", "PetType"};
        String where = null;
        String groupBy = null;
        String having = null;
        String orderBy = null;
        String limit = null;

        cursor = db.query(Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME,
                            null,
                            where,
                            null,
                            groupBy,
                            having,
                            orderBy,
                            limit);

        // Return Cursor
        return cursor;
    }

    public void DisplayCurrentRecord(View view)
    {
        String temp;
        final String EOF = "<eof>";
        TextView tempOwner = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvOwnerOutput);
        TextView tempPetName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPetNameOutput);
        TextView tempPetType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPetTypeOutput);

        if (cursor.isBeforeFirst()) { cursor.moveToNext(); }

        if (cursor != null)
        {
            cursor.moveToNext();

            // While the cursor is not after the end of the result set
            if (cursor.isAfterLast())
            {
                tempOwner.setText(EOF);
                tempPetName.setText(EOF);
                tempPetType.setText(EOF);
            }
            else
            {
                temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_OWNER));
                tempOwner.setText(temp);
                temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME));
                tempPetName.setText(temp);
                temp = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_TYPE));
                tempPetType.setText(temp);

                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }


    }

    public void ResetRecordSet(View view)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    }
}
```

**Contract**

```
package com.example.devonryder.week9;

import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.database.sqlite.*;

/**
 * Created by Devon Ryder on 3/8/2017.
 */

public final class Contract {
    // Stop instantiation via private constructor
    private Contract()
    {
    }

    // Table info in the schema
    public static class dbEntry implements BaseColumns
    {
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "pet";
        public static final String COLUMN_OWNER = "owner";
        public static final String COLUMN_PET_NAME = "PetName";
        public static final String COLUMN_PET_AGE = "PetAge";
        public static final String COLUMN_PET_TYPE = "PetType";
    }


}
```

**Helper**

```
package com.example.devonryder.week9;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.*;

/**
 * Created by Devon Ryder on 3/8/2017.
 */
public class Helper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pets.db";

    // Constructor -- Calls base class constructor
    public Helper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null , DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    Contract.dbEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_OWNER + " TEXT," +
                    Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME + " TEXT," +
                    Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_AGE + " INT," +
                    Contract.dbEntry.COLUMN_PET_TYPE + " TEXT)";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES =
            "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Contract.dbEntry.TABLE_NAME;
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.devonryder.week9.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:text="Insert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnInsert"
        android:onClick="Insert" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvInsertOutput" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Owner name "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnInsert"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnInsert"
        android:layout_marginBottom="85dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvOwner" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Pet Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvPetName" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Pet Type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPetName"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPetName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvPetName" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/tvOwnerOutput" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvPetName"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/tvOwnerOutput"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/tvOwnerOutput"
        android:id="@+id/tvPetNameOutput" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:id="@+id/tvPetTypeOutput" />

    <Button
        android:text="Reset Records"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnInsert"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvOwner"
        android:onClick="ResetRecordSet"
        android:id="@+id/btnResetRecords" />

    <Button
        android:text="Display Current Record"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnResetRecords"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnResetRecords"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnResetRecords"
        android:onClick="DisplayCurrentRecord"
        android:id="@+id/btnDisplayCurrentRecord" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

All help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Seems that in my Insert method I was not actually inserting to the PetType column as I was putting values to the PetName twice.

Additionally, I was only getting 3 (half) the results because I was moving the Cursor both at the start and the end of the Insert method.

Comment: You're calling `moveToNext()` twice in the `DisplayCurrentRecord()` method. That would explain why you're only seeing half the records.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, seems I was! Is it fine to have if (cursor.isBeforeFirst()) { cursor.moveToNext(); }? As I understand, the Cursor initially starts before the first result of the db.query.

Comment: Yep, that's correct. A fresh `Cursor` will start before the first record. You could simplify your handing of this a little bit by just checking what `moveToNext()` returns. If it returns `true`, then it was able to move to the next record, and you can display it. If `false`, it's done, and you can show your EOF message.

Comment: I on phone,  slow and tiny , @MikeM. U should write the whole answer

Comment: @PavneetSingh I'm on a phone, too. :-) That's why I didn't see your answer until after I'd commented, or I would've commented on your answer to add that. You're more than welcome to edit that stuff into your answer, and undelete it, so ryderd can accept it, and close out their question. Thanks, though. Cheers!

Comment: @MikeM. i admire your supporting nature although the answer should be rightfully yours because u supported the OP more than me  :)